# Explanation of the presence of a character in the output

Tags: c, operator-precedence

The following program:

```
int main( )
{
    static char s[25]="The cocaine man";
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    ch=s[++i];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch=s[i++];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch=i++[s];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch=++i[s];
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is :

> > hhe!

The `hhe` is all right,but the '!' in the output is confusing me.The statement `ch=++i[s]` is responsible for this. It should be intepreted like:

> > ch=*(s+ ++i);

causing i to be 4 due to prefix increment and using it to fetch 'c' but '!',I don't get that and plus after this operation,I printed the value of 'i' to check and it was 4 not 3. What is the problem, I don't get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is

```
ch=++(i[s]);
```

Where `i[s]=' '`. And in ASCII Code, `'!' = ' ' + 1`

Comment: ,why is the output printf("%c",str[3]) i.e. The value where ' ' is stored is printing '!' in output

Comment: Because `++` modified `i[s]` (`s[3]`, or maybe `str[3]` you meant).

Answer (score 0):

The operator [] has precedence against arithmetic operators. Knowing this `++i[s]` is equivalent to `++(i[s])` as john said.